# Question on related rates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that there is a cylindrical container whose height is 10 meters and whose base
radius is 1 meter. The bottom of the container has a hole, through which water leaks
out at a rate (in meter cubes per minute) equal to the the height of the water in the
container. A pump is turned on to fill the container with water. The rate (in meter
cubes per minute) at which water is pumped into the container t minutes after the
pump is turned on is t divided by the volume of water in the container at time t. If
the height of water in the container at t = 0 is 1 meter, find a formula for the volume
of water in the container at time t.

I honestly have no clue where to start and which variables to use a liitle general guide to the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: Take $L=$ leaking amount in $\frac{\text{m}^3}{\text{s}}$ from the bottom. What is the equation to calculate $L$? Then, consider $P=$ pump rate. What is the equation to calculate $P$?

Comment: When you have calculated $L$ and $P$, the differential equation for the total amount $V$ is
$$
\frac{d V}{d t} = P - L
$$
Plug in the equations that you have created, and solve the equation.

Comment: @MattiP. When they say the water leaks out at a rate proportional to the height of water in the container so would it be L =( -Pi * k*h)/T where k is a constant?

Comment: The problem statement says: "leaks out at a rate (in meter cubes per minute) equal to the the height of the water in the container" - so I would write just
$$
L = h = \frac{V}{2 \pi R}
$$
where $h$ is the height, $R=1~\text{m}$ and $V$ is the volume. How did you come up with something like $\frac{-\pi k h}{T}$ ?

Comment: @Matti P. Ok i see so i could write P as simply P = t/v and simply solve the ODE?

Comment: Well, the final form of the equation depends on what you will choose as the unknown variable - is it volume $V$ or height $h$. So choose one of those and then rewrite the differential equation.